# Sum of a general sequence

Tags: limits

How we can solve following general series:

$\sum^{\infty}_{x=0}xf^{x}$

provided that $f=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$ where $0<\theta<1$.

Comment: I know the exact sum exists through MATHEMATICA but I want details. I require a general formula for such sums.

Comment: It would be helpful for other users to help you if you can explain what have you tried except using mathematics?

Comment: I am not very good in mathematics so I tried some basic formulas of sums of series but no success to due the x factor that is multiplied with f. Otherwise, its a simple Infinite Geometric series with sum $1-\theta$.

Comment: it might be useful if you can try considering given sum as derivative of some thing... you should get this idea as you have $xf^x$ which is very much same as $n.x^{n-1}$ which is derivative of $x^n$...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, $f = \frac{\theta}{\theta+1}, \theta \in (0, 1)$ simply means $f \in (0, \frac 1 2)$. Then, $$\sum xf^x = f\sum xf^{x-1} = f\frac{d\sum f^x}{df}$$

Likewise, $$\sum x(x-1)f^x = f^2\sum x(x-1)f^{x-2} = f^2 \frac{d^2 \sum f^x} {d^2 f}$$

Comment: this is exactly what came in my mind in first instance :) :)

Comment: For this question $\sum_{x=0}^{infty}(\frac{\theta}{1+\theta})^{x}=(\theta+1)$. If I take derivative of this sum w.r.t $\theta$ than I get 1, which gives me f. Which is correct or not?

Comment: @user106558 Derivative is w.r.t $f$. That's because $((\frac \theta {1+\theta})^x)' \neq x(\frac \theta {1+\theta})^{x-1}$ which is a key property.

Comment: What about this sum

$\sum^{\infty}_{x=0}x(x-1)f^{x}$.

I have tried to employed the same procedure but I am getting a very long expression. Which is making mess. Any help.

Comment: $\sum f^{x}=(1+\theta)$ so the two derivatives will be zero.

Comment: @SHAH1180 what is $\frac {d\theta} {df}$? It's not $1$, I assure you.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė, I didn't get $\frac{d\theta}{d f}$?

Comment: I have $0<\theta<1$ and $f=\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}$.

Comment: I have learned taking derivative w.r.t to a linear variable like $\theta$ only. But how one can take derivative w.r.t $\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}$?

Comment: @SHAH1180, if $f = \frac {\theta} {1+\theta}$ then $\theta = \dots$?

Comment: Definitely $\theta$ will be $\frac{f}{1-f}$.

Comment: @SHAH1180 So $\frac {d\theta}{df} = \frac{d \frac{f}{1-f}}{df}$ isn't it? And $\frac {d^2\theta}{d^2f} = \frac{d^2 \frac{f}{1-f}}{d^2f} \neq 0$.